# Excel vba - Search for data in 2 columns then move row to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have to sort through several hundred rows in a spreadsheet. I would like to try and automate this task with vba code but I don’t know how to go about it.

In the spreadsheet I need to search down column ‘A’ (until the end of the data) and identify any cells in column ‘A’ that contain the text/word “asset”. If a cell does contain the text “asset” check along the same row to the cell in column ‘N’. If the corresponding cell on the same row in column ‘N’ is blank, move the entire row to a new sheet called ‘Removed’

Can anyone please help with some vba code

Thanks
Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know how many rows exactly you need to check or do you need a function that stops automatically?

```
Sub CopyPaste()

Dim MyRange as Range
Dim Current_Range as Range

'Nb_Rows can be any integer, even higher than the real number of rows.
For i = 1 To Nb_Rows
If Range("A" & i).Value = "asset" Then
    If Range("N" & i).Value = "" Then
        Set Current_Range = Cells(i, 1)
        If MyRange Is Nothing Then
            Set MyRange = Current_Range
        Else
            Set MyRange = Application.Union(MyRange, Current_Range)
        End If
    End If
End If
Next i

If MyRange Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    MyRange.EntireRow.Cut
    Sheets("Removed").Paste
End If

End Sub
```

This piece of code should work. 
I used `Nb_Rows` for the loop, maybe you should change that value.
Be aware that I copy/paste the rows, meaning that they will stay in the first sheet. I also assume that you launch the macro when the first sheet is activated.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your quick reply. The amount of rows vary from one spreadsheet to another. Normally from 100 to 6-700 so really need a function that stops automatically (unless I can just change Nb to 1000 so it checks down to line 1000)?. Also I need to have them removed from the original sheet so need them to be cut and pasted (can I just swap Copy for Cut)? Thanks

Comment: You can set `Nb_Rows` at 1000, it will check down to line 1000 without cutting empty lines so it won't change anything. And you can replace `.Copy` with `.Cut`. This will only work if Sheet 'Removed' is empty.